# PHP - Bitwise as access control

Tags: php, mysql, bitwise-operators

I am using bitwise as access control for pages, in the user table there is a page_access column. In menu table there is a permid column.

4 pages in menu table (and permid):

- map 1
- import 2
- users 4
- testing 8

I then use mysql to pull menu... (getuserdets($liuid,'page_access') - returns logged in users page_access from mysql)

```
$sql = "SELECT name,page FROM menu WHERE permid & ".getuserdets($liuid,'page_access');
```

This works perfectly.

However the equivalent in PHP does not appear to, using the following:

```
$sql = "SELECT name,page,permid FROM menu ORDER BY permid";
$res = mysqli_query($mysqli,$sql);
while($row = mysqli_fetch_row($res)) {
    $checked = '';
    if ($row[2] & getuserdets($_REQUEST['id'],'page_access')) { $checked = 'checked'; }
    $access .= $row[2]." -- ".getuserdets($_REQUEST['id'],'page_access')." $checked<br>";
    << SNIP FORM CHECKBOXES >>
}
```

This seems to display incorrectly ($access is a temp var to show this) from 2 separate users, one works as expected the other does not...

```
All should be checked - (wrong)
1 -- 15 checked
2 -- 15
4 -- 15
8 -- 15 

Two checked - (correct)
1 -- 3 checked
2 -- 3 checked
4 -- 3
8 -- 3
```

Can't see the difference in PHP code to MySQL query and all 4 pages are returned as expected for a permid of 15

Comment: Seems like a silly design.  Use the set type instead:  https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/set.html.

Comment: You should know that `$_REQUEST['id']` can be manipulated by the client.